# Python serial fails to write

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I am using Python 2.7 and serial v 2.6 to listen to a serial port.  I can listen to the port just fine, but I cannot write to the port.

```
import serial
cp = 5
br = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(5,br)

a = ser.readline()
```

Using this, I can listen to the outcoming data stream.  However, if I want to change the status of the instrument (e.g. set GPS to off) I would write a command:

```
ser.write('gps=off')
```

When I do this, I get "6L" returned and the gps stay on.  However, if I connect via TeraTerm I can see the data stream in in real time.  While the data streams in I can type gps=off followed by a return and suddenly my GPS is off.  Why is my command in Python not working like TeraTerm?

UPDATE

If I instead do 
    a = ser.write('gps=on')

"a" is assigned value of 6.  I also tried sending a "junk" command via

```
a = ser.write('lkjdflksdjflksdjf')
```

with "a" assigned a value of 17, so it seems to be assigning the length of the string to a, which does not make sense.

Comment: The obvious thing to try is append a line terminator to your output string.

Comment: Do you mean ser.write('gps.off\r\n')?  I tried that and it only changed the returned value ("14L" I think...though I am not sure).

Comment: I don't know Python, so does *"fails to write"* mean that the syscall is returning an error (the conventional meaning), or that the device does not respond to your expectations (how you seem to be using it)?  If the latter, then what is this *"instrument"*?

Comment: By "fails to write" I mean the instrument (a meteorological sonde) does not change status.  The confusing part is by issuing the command (gps=of/off) in TeraTerm the status is changed perfectly.  I have never dealt with sending commands via serial in Python so I assumed I was doing something wrong, though after reading tutorials I see nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the ser.write commands were getting stuck in buffer (I am not sure of that, but that is my suspicion).  When I checked the input buffer I found it to be full.  After flushing it out I was able to write to the instrument.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(5, 9600)

# the buffer immediately receives data, so ensure it is empty before writing command
while ser.inWaiting()>0:
    ser.read(1)

# now issue command
ser.write('gps=off\r')
```

That works.